# Microsoft Onenote keyboard shortcut

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I'm currently trying to organise all the notes I created over last 1 year in Microsoft OneNote. What is the keyboard shortcut for `delete section` in Microsoft OneNote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl-Shift-G`, then `Shift-F10`, then `D`